# <table:column> Roo-tag for property of referenced entity

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-roo, taglib

I've got a two classes (pupil, class) in a Roo-project and their scaffolded views.

pupil and class have a 1:1 relationship

In the list.jspx of pupil I'd like to display a column for a property of class.

I don't know the correct attributes to give to the table:column-tag.
This following example gives the error:

> SpelEvaluationException: EL1027Epos 4): Indexing into type 'com.pupil' is not supported

```
<table:table data="${pupil}" duplicate="true" id="l_com_pupil" path="/admin/pupil" z="user-managed">
   <table:column id="c_com_pupil_pupilName" property="pupilName" z="user-managed"/>
   <!-- I'd like to display the attribute teacher_name of the class 'class' here but it doesn't work -->
   <table:column id="c_com_pupil_class_teacherName" property="teacherName"  z="user-managed"/>
</table:table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it, not for listing, but rather for showing the name of the teacher when you view the pupil entity:

- Edit the controller and specifically the method show (in the java file, not in the aj file, of course).
- Add an attribute to your UI Model, for instance "teacherName" (use Model.addAttribute), where you populate the teacherName with the desired name.
- Add in the show.jspx file something like:

  `<div><label for="_pupilTeacher">Teacher Name:</label><div class="box">${teacherName}</div></div><br/>`

(alternatively, you could create a new tagx file with your own parameters)

Hope it helped.

Radu

Answer (score 3):

Instead of messing around with the jspx files, you can simply do this by implementing a converter for the `Teacher` entity within the `ApplicationServiceFactoryBean.java`.

See the below conversion method for an example.

```
static class com.mycompany.test.controllers.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean.TeacherConverter implements org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter<com.mycompany.test.domain.master.Teacher, java.lang.String>  {
        public String convert(Teacher teacher) {
            return new StringBuilder().append(teacher.getName()).toString();
        }
}
```

By default, Roo generates these converters and they are stored within the `ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean_Roo_ConversionService.aj` file.

You can push in refactor the related method for the `Teacher` entity from this aspectJ file into the 
`ApplicationServiceFactoryBean.java` file and then implement your own conversion which will be used to show the `Teacher` name across the application as in the above example.

Cheers and all the best with Roo!

Comment: I rather would like to have the teachername in its own column and not in the same column with the name of the class. For this purpose I can't use your workaround.

Comment: First understand the answer and try it without assuming things. All the best. :)

Comment: I pushed in all methods of the ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean weeks ago and adjusted them. Some even use what you describe but here it just doesn't do what I describe in the question. I could show pupilName and classes attribute teacherName in one column but not in seperate ones.