# Spring roo scaffold action on an existing controller

Tags: spring-roo

I am new to spring roo and I am having issues trying to scaffold with an entity an already generated controller.

If I scaffold a new controller with an entity I get generated all the aspectJ files automatically, however if I try to scaffold an already generated controller (see example code) it generates a ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean which I am not sure what to use it for.

```
`controller class --class ~.web.MyController
controller scaffold --class ~.web.MyController --entity ~.model.User`
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`ApplicationServiceFactoryBean.java` is used to store converters for your entities which will be used for display purposes throughout the application.

A sample usage of this file is available in the following answer.

[<table:column> Roo-tag for property of referenced entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753383/tablecolumn-roo-tag-for-property-of-referenced-entity/7764349#7764349)

Cheers!!!